# Visual Studio and windows store error 0x80073cf9

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

when I use windows store for update application and when in the visual studio for create new project univesal 
show error 0x80073cf9

Comment: 0x80073cf9 = 15609 = ERROR_INSTALL_FAILED look in eventlog for more details

Comment: which event log ???

Comment: the one from Windows

Answer (score 0):

As this error could be caused by a variety of reasons thus I think you could try as many solutions as you can.

First, please check if the folder “AUInstallAgent” is missing from the Windows folder. If it is, you might need to create a new one, then rename it as “AUInstallAgent” and reboot your device.

Another method is to wipe the Store caches. You could type “wsreset” command in Start menu and try to launch the Store again.

Also, I thinks this [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_store/error-0x80073cf9-in-windows-store/25bdd009-fc6b-4860-9e74-27cd565049b5) from answers forum can be helpful to you.